# Displaying SQLite data in textview returning null

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, null

```
MainData myDBHlpr = new MainData(getActivity()); 

Cursor csr = myDBHlpr.getAllQuestions(UsageSettings.this);
while (csr.moveToFirst()) {
    mMostMessagesSent.setText(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("Reviews")));
    mMostMessagesSent.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

I checked row count and it showed 16

Then i checked

```
Log.d("TAG", csr.getString(cst.getColumnIndex("Reviews")));
```

And it showed error saying Log needs a message(Which means its null)

But why is it showing null even when the table has 16rows and column name exists

HELPER METHOD

```
public Cursor getAllQuestions(UsageSettings usageSettings) {

    return this.getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

Comment: Log.d("TAG, csr.getString(cst.getColumnIndex("Reviews))))  are you missing quotes " " ??

Comment: No i just typed that line so i missed it...  @Mr.Roshan

Comment: Where you write Log.d("TAG", csr.getString(cst.getColumnIndex("Reviews"))); ?

Comment: i wrote it and i emoved because it gav an error... @MohammadrezaKhatami

Comment: Had written it just below Color.White line @MohammadrezaKhatami

Comment: Alright. So you mean it's below Color.White and inside while loop ?

Comment: Yes @MohammadrezaKhatami Whats the mistake??

Comment: I don't know at the moment. But let me sure about your code by posting it completely.

Comment: What more code do you want? Modal class? @MohammadrezaKhatami

Comment: I'm not sure what the class name is. But i want to be sure that line of code that produce error is placed inside the while loop. because it is not clear for me that cs.getString... is not working for the second call.

Comment: 1. Be sure that cs.getString(..) does not returning null in Log.d(..) method by watching it in debug mode. 2. Making sure that logger is configured correctly in your project by passing a simple string to it to making sure that works!

Comment: Can u look through my code via teamviewer please? @MohammadrezaKhatami

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183701/discussion-between-mohammadreza-khatami-and-nikki-zepher).